# R dplyr: group by without aggregate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to perform a group_by without an aggregate function on the following data set:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 product = c("A","B","C","D","E","A","A","B","C"),
                 year = c(2018,2018,2019,2018,2018,2017,2018,2019,2018))
  ID product year
1  1       A 2018
2  1       B 2018
3  1       C 2019
4  2       D 2018
5  2       E 2018
6  3       A 2017
7  3       A 2018
8  3       B 2019
9  3       C 2018
```

I want to create 2 separate datasets: one for product and one for year. Problem is that when I try group_by it needs an aggregate function and I don't want that. I just need the unique combinations of ID and PRODUCT in one case, and of ID and YEAR in the other case (so 2 separate dataframes)

PRODUCT

```
  ID product
1  1       A
2  1       B
3  1       C
4  2       D
5  2       E
6  3       A
7  3       B
8  3       C
```

YEAR:

```
  ID year
1  1 2018
2  1 2019
3  2 2018
4  3 2017
5  3 2018
6  3 2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `group_by` here since you want unique rows for selected columns. If you want unique combination of many columns you can do that using `lapply`.

```
list_data <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) unique(cbind(df[1], x)))
```

---

If there are only two columns and we need to use `dplyr`, we can use `distinct`.

```
Product <- df %>% distinct(ID, product)
YEAR <- df %>% distinct(ID, year)
```

Comment: You can also do `df %>% distinct(ID, year)`, since `distinct()` takes variable names.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is better option. It just slipped out of my mind.